# Apache vhost directory not loading sites

Tags: macos, apache, vhosts

I moved from linux to a mac. I have Apache and php setup.

Now apache seems to only load the first virtual host listed. It also only loads it in the browser via local host and not the sitename. Its been 3 days hunting the net or solutions nothing seems to work.

now if i make the document root for the virtual host eg. /Library/WebServer/Documents/ then it works. If i add an extra directory it fails eg. /Library/WebServer/Documents/livingahimsa.co.uk

here is the config: ( I have tried the doc root with quotes and without)

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       ahimsainvestments.com
127.0.0.1       livingahimsa.co.uk
127.0.0.1       ahimsavillage.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

and vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/ahimsainvestments.com 
    ServerName ahimsainvestments.com 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/livingahimsa.co.uk 
    ServerName livingahimsa.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/ahimsavillage.com 
    ServerName ahimsavillage.com
```

pache2/httpd.conf

Comment: Is this Apache 2.2?  If so, you must add NameVirtualHost directive.  If it is Apache 2.4, then...  I can't see a problem with this config.  Any logs in LogLevel debug?  Check https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CommonMisconfigurations

Comment: hi it is version 2.4.29 osx high seirra will check logs again

Comment: it was safari and its ssl issues server was fine, worked fine in firefox